# How to disable touch during a call

Tags: lock-screens, calls, htc-one

When I call with the smartphone (HTC one M7) I often click the screen with the cheek.

I have notice that on Samsung Galaxy tab 8.0 when I call is there an option that disable the touch. Is it possible to import/install this feature also on HTC One?

Comment: Is your M7 rooted? If so, you might wish to check [this post on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=39995809&postcount=5) for a possible fix.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for "proximity sensor" settings.  If your proximity sensor is enabled and your screen doesn't go black when the phone is to your ear, the sensor (looks like a tiny camera lens, usually in the upper screen frame) may be covered by a screen protector or case, or may have failed.  If you can't find proximity sensor settings, your provider's tech support should be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, used the *#0*# thing to test the proximity sensor, it seemed to be fine (screen went green whenever my hand got close to the screen).  Went to phone -> setting -> call and disabled the "turn off screen during calls" thing, power off, removed the battery, blew into every hole I could find, reinstalled the battery, powered on, went back and re-enabled the "turn off screen during calls" thing and now it works.  Go figure.